# How to convert SimpleXMLObject into PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

Consider the following code:

```
$string = '<device>
    <id>1234</id>
    <label>118</label>
    <username>root</username>
    <password>helloWorld</password>
    <hardware>
        <memory>4GB RAM</memory>
        <storage_drives>
            <storage_drive_1>2TB SATA 7,200RPM</storage_drive_1>
            <storage_drive_2>1TB SATA 7,200RPM</storage_drive_2>
            <storage_drive_3>Not Applicable</storage_drive_3>
            <storage_drive_4>Not Applicable</storage_drive_4>
        </storage_drives>
    </hardware>
</device>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$deviceDetails = Array();
foreach($xml as $element){
    $tag = $element->getName();
    $deviceDetails +=  Array($tag => '$element->$tag)',
        );
    }
```

Output `$detailsDetails` array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [id] => $element->$tag)
    [label] => $element->$tag)
    [username] => $element->$tag)
    [password] => $element->$tag)
    [hardware] => $element->$tag)
)
```

which is wrong.

My question is, **how to make `$element->$tag` work?**

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes (or none at all)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Book Of Zeus** code wrapped in function to make it work recursively:

```
function xml2array($xml)
{
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($xml as $element)
    {
        $tag = $element->getName();
        $e = get_object_vars($element);
        if (!empty($e))
        {
            $arr[$tag] = $element instanceof SimpleXMLElement ? xml2array($element) : $e;
        }
        else
        {
            $arr[$tag] = trim($element);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
print_r(xml2array($xml));

Array
(
    [id] => 1234
    [label] => 118
    [username] => root
    [password] => helloWorld
    [hardware] => Array
    (
        [memory] => 4GB RAM
        [storage_drives] => Array
        (
            [storage_drive_1] => 2TB SATA 7,200RPM
            [storage_drive_2] => 1TB SATA 7,200RPM
            [storage_drive_3] => Not Applicable
            [storage_drive_4] => Not Applicable
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @dfsq - this seems to not work through the entire array, it's like it only returns the first entry for me... is that possible?

Comment: @Shackrock Check out the solution from Book Of Zeus

Comment: @shackrock is right, this is great for SimpleXMLElements that do not have any lists. For my own purposes I just removed the `$arr[$tag] =` ternary line and split it into full conditions, in the case `$element` is a SimpleXMLElement, do `$arr[$tag][] = xml2array($element);`. Note the **[]**. Not sure if that's what others would need, however.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
$string = '<device>
  <id>1234</id>
  <label>118</label>
  <username>root</username>
  <password>helloWorld</password>
  <hardware>
    <memory>4GB RAM</memory>
     <storage_drives>
      <storage_drive_1>2TB SATA 7,200RPM</storage_drive_1>
      <storage_drive_2>1TB SATA 7,200RPM</storage_drive_2>
      <storage_drive_3>Not Applicable</storage_drive_3>
      <storage_drive_4>Not Applicable</storage_drive_4>
    </storage_drives>
  </hardware>
</device>';
  
$xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($string)), 1);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1234
    [label] => 118
    [username] => root
    [password] => helloWorld
    [hardware] => Array
        (
            [memory] => 4GB RAM
            [storage_drives] => Array
                (
                    [storage_drive_1] => 2TB SATA 7,200RPM
                    [storage_drive_2] => 1TB SATA 7,200RPM
                    [storage_drive_3] => Not Applicable
                    [storage_drive_4] => Not Applicable
                )

        )

)
```

or if you don't like this, you can use a PHP class like: http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/

or view **dfsq** answer

Comment: It doesn't work recursively. [storage_drives] => SimpleXMLElement Object.

Comment: +1 for this method. Although it not really good technic to do like this but for simple small objects it doesn't make sense to use functions etc. to convert object to array.

Comment: by the way, no need of (array) befor simplexml_load_string

Comment: I prefer your method for sure, I just wanted to show a quick & easy way to do it!

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.