# How to parse this XML to PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hiyo,

I frequently work with XML and PHP but this specific return I'm getting is throwing a curveball as to how to get it in PHP. I would LOVE if I could convert the "$attribute" and "VALUE" to an assoc array some how.

Really stumped and frustrated
-Ray

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[MULTIPLE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [SINGLE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [KEY] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => address
                                    )

                                [VALUE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [null] => null
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => aim
                                    )

                                [VALUE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [null] => null
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => auth
                                    )

                                [VALUE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [null] => null
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
```

UPDATE:
Here is the XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RESPONSE>
<MULTIPLE>
<SINGLE>
<KEY name="address"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="aim"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="auth"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="city"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="confirmed"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="country"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="deleted"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="department"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="description"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="email"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="emailstop"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="error"><VALUE>no match found for idnumber = 301942</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="firstname"><VALUE null="null"/>
...
```

I know how to parse the XML when it is formed in the manner described in that tutorial. But this specific case has me stumped as how to access the nodes I need (Either through SimpleXML object or converting it to a PHP array WITHOUT going through the nodes like this:

```
$xml_obj->MULTIPLE->SINGLE->KEY[9]->VALUE
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778814/simplexml-php-convert-simplexmlobject-into-php-array/7778950#7778950

Comment: Post your XML and expected output instead of var_dump output.

Comment: Added an update to the question

Answer (score 0):

give [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp) a read, it will show you a brief tutorial